# Servlet attributes not available in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a strange problem.  My servlet values only show up when the isAuthenticated is true here, not when it's false.  This is using Shiro, if that matters.  I have looked at the console of hte browser and it's not redirecting or anything, but my values only show on the JSP when the if below is true.

```
public void service(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse) throws ServletException, IOException {
        if(SecurityUtils.getSubject() != null && SecurityUtils.getSubject().isAuthenticated()) {
            servletRequest.setAttribute("loginStatus",
                    "true");
        } else {
            servletRequest.setAttribute("loginStatus",
                    "false");
        }
        servletRequest.setAttribute("testValue", "Test Value");
        servletRequest.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(servletRequest, servletResponse);
```

Here is the JSP

```
<html>
    <body>
    <p>
        This is the index page, authenticated is <b>${loginStatus}</b>
    </p>
    <p>
        The test value is ${testValue}
    </p>
    <ul>
        <li><a href='app-login'>Login Page</a></li>
        <li><a href='test'>Test link (protected)</a></li>
        <li><a href='logout'>Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
</html>
        }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: These are not 'servlet attributes'. You are setting *request* attributes, and they will be lost on the next request. You should be setting them in the session.

Comment: Why do they work only if the if statement is true (and there is one that is not even inside the if block?  They are done the *exact* same way and there is no redirect.  I load the page in a new browser and it does not work.  Login and reload the same page (no redirect) and it works until I log out.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out index.jsp was a poor name for that page.  Wildfly was just rendering the index.jsp page when my url was '/', instead of letting the servlet at that URL render it.

I changed the jsp to index-view.jsp and it works as expected.